# How should language aliases be used with datetime2?

Tags: languages, datetime2

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{useregional}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\begin{document}
  \today
\end{document}
```

As expected, this produces:

[image: superscripted ordinals]

Perhaps somewhat naïvely, I would expect the following code to produce the same results:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{useregional}
\DTMlangsetup[british]{ord=raise}

\begin{document}
  \today
\end{document}
```

but it does not:

[image: non-superscripted ordinals]

The documentation for `datetime2` does suggest that language aliases may not be entirely equal. What I don't understand is how to distinguish them conceptually. What principled distinction does the package draw between `british` and `en-GB` for example, which would make sense of the apparent discrepancies?

Comment: Is it that `datetime2` recognises language aliases only for certain purposes and this just ain't one of them, so since `british` is an alias, it does zilch whereas since `en-GB` is the module name, it does have an effect? But this would clearly be a recipe for end-user confusion on a massive scale: it is completely counter-intuitive. If aliases just can't be properly supported, surely the package would just not provide them at all and then just say 'use `en-GB` for British English etc.'. That is, partial support seems so obviously problematic that it is hard to imagine its being deliberate...?

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

If you want to adjust the style of a particular `datetime2` module, you need to use the name of that module. So for the `en-GB` module (defined by `datetime2-en-GB.ldf`) you need to use `en-GB` as the identifier. Note that you can also just do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional,warn=false]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup{ord=raise}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

The language alias is picked up by `tracklang` which is internally used by `datetime2` to determine the required language/region module, so it's a `babel` alias rather than a `datetime2` alias.

**Long Answer:**

As much as I like LaTeX, the international support is messy. 
This is, presumably, due to its age and the general lack of consistent localisation support in computers when it was first developed¹ (and even more so when TeX was developed). This has resulted in fragmented and incompatible internationalisation branches. So there is `babel` with its own set of aliases (such as `british` and `UKenglish`), `polyglossia` with a different interface and some different aliases (such as `variant=british` or `variant=uk`), `translator` with another set of aliases (`BritishEnglish`), and then there are packages for a specific language, such as `ngerman`. There are other language-related packages that I've heard of, but never used, and I suspect there are also some that I have not only never used but also never heard of.

In additional to all this, there are classes and packages that provide their own language support with different syntax. For example, the `isodoc` class has the syntax `language=en-GB` (or `language=enGB`).

This results in a nightmare for package developers who want to add international support without forcing the user into using a specific language package (such as `babel`). It ends up with a complicated mass of `\@ifpackageloaded{polyglossia}` ... `\@ifpackageloaded{babel}` ... `\@ifpackageloaded{translator}` ... (which ones have I missed!)

The easy solution is to tell the user to supply the required language variant for each package that provides localisation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[british]{some-package}
\usepackage[language=en-GB]{some-other-package}
```

Or:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
\usepackage[british]{some-package}
\usepackage[language=en-GB]{some-other-package}
```

This puts LaTeX well behind modern alternatives. The document language(s) and region(s) would be much better set globally so that all packages that provide regional support don't have to jump through hoops trying to work out this information or demand that the user repeats the information.

It was for this reason that I wrote [`tracklang`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tracklang) to help package developers track down the language and regional options requested by the user without having to burden their code with a load of nested conditionals. Unfortunately it's limited by the fact that some language packages don't provide a convenient way for `tracklang` to pick up the regional variant provided by the user.

For example, with `polyglossia` there is a conditional `\if@british@locale` which is set to true by `variant=uk` and `variant=british` and is false otherwise. If this conditional is true, it doesn't tell me whether the user used `uk` or `british`. If the conditional is false, it doesn't tell me if the user used `australian`, `newzealand`, `us`, etc.

So `british` / `UKenglish` are *babel* aliases, `british` / `uk` are *polyglossia* aliases, `BritishEnglish` is a *translator* setting, etc. So although I could provide a mapping from `british` to `en-GB` or a mapping from `UKenglish` to `en-GB`, I would also need to add aliases for every other possible language package, otherwise users would be puzzled as to why some aliases work but others don't, and this really isn't feasible as I'd have to constantly monitor all language package development.

There is a further complication for `datetime2`, which is that the regional variants provided by `babel`, `polyglossia` etc aren't always sufficiently specific.

Suppose I'm in England writing a document in English and I want to display the time including the time zone. (For simplicity the example below just uses `\DTMdisplayzone` but in real documents this is more likely to occur with commands like `\DTMnow`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

UTC+0: \DTMdisplayzone{00}{00}.
UTC+1: \DTMdisplayzone{01}{00}.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

UTC+0: GMT. UTC+1: BST.

However, suppose instead I'm in the Republic of Ireland and I'm writing a document in English. The time zone mapping for UTC+1 is now incorrect as it should be IST (Irish Summer Time) not BST (British Summer Time), so in this case, aside from political sensitivities, `british` is an appropriate option, and it really needs to be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[en-IE]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

UTC+0: \DTMdisplayzone{00}{00}.
UTC+1: \DTMdisplayzone{01}{00}.

\end{document}
```

This now produces:

UTC+0: GMT. UTC+1: IST.

The file `datetime2-en-GB.ldf` is no longer loaded, but instead `datetime2-en-IE.ldf` is loaded and the style setting used in the optional argument of `\DTMlangsetup` should now be `en-IE`.

Similarly, if I was in, say, Malta, I'd need to use `en-MT` to get the UTC+1 time zone displayed as CET.²

So the `british` alias can be ambiguous, and I think it's better practice to know the actual name of the regional module or just omit the optional argument to `\DTMlangsetup`, as this makes the code more portable in the event that it's reused in a document that uses a different alias.

---

¹If I recall correctly, LaTeX2.09 didn't even have commands like `\contentsname`. They're certainly not listed in the index of the 2.09 user manual from 1986.

²Not all the `datetime2` language modules have regional variants with ISO codes as there's a limit to my world knowledge, but I'm hoping that maintainers of those modules will fill in the blanks caused by my ignorance.