# How to get automatic date generated in a LaTeX file?

Tags: datetime

I tried using the `datetime` package, but it doesn't display the date in the format I want. What I would like is something like `August 30, 2015`.

How do I do this?

Comment: `\today{}` is one method

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) package:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `datetime`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newdateformat{monthdayyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH]~\THEDAY, \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}

\monthdayyeardate\today

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know how I could push this to the right side of the page? I tried using `\hfill`, but it doesn't do anything. Using `\begin{flushright}` causes an error for some reason.

Comment: @AlanH Under normal circumstances `\hfill` should be enough; if it's not working for you, we need the code you are using. Please consider then opening a fresh new question.

Comment: You could use `datetime2` but you might be happier not doing so :(.

Comment: @cfr Why is this so?

Comment: I wish I'd never tried to update. I cannot make it work. I cannot even, really, figure out how it is supposed to work or what I am supposed to do with it. I'm sure it is fine for English. I'm just using `datetime` with a fixed language file. That works fine and was straightforward to do. The original file for Welsh has Breton mixed in with it. So does the `datetime2` version so I tried to correct it but I can't. Polyglossia is corrected. Babel is not but would be easy. `datetime` is easy but cannot be changed (except locally). `datetime2`... I'm sure it is not impossible, but it sure seems so.

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260989/how-does-showdow-work-in-datetime2) is me just failing to get to grips with using it in *English*.  I therefore have a partial language module written for Welsh but I've given up: if I can't even get to grips with the English version, I can't hope to translate it. Especially since translation essentially requires writing a chunk of the package's functionality. Whereas in `datetime`, you just really have to translate the strings, in `datetime2` language modules must add functionality which plays nicely within a skeletal framework.

Comment: See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261641/how-do-i-extract-a-month-name-in-datetime2) which basically concerns a similar point: that `datetime2`, unlike `datetime`, does not provide a common language-agnostic set of commands for typesetting dates. This is part of why creating a language module is a nightmare. But it also makes it impossible to create a document where you can be sure things will come out correctly if you switch the preamble from one language to another. `datetime` still seems the best option for multi-lingual to me, despite its limitations.

Comment: And [me again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261098/how-should-language-aliases-be-used-with-datetime2?s=9|1.0903). I seem to be peculiar in having so much trouble although not utterly alone.